# Kernelpanic Fedora 18 with kernel 3.9.2-200

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-panic, fedora

Since upgrading to kernel 3.9 I now get this error every time at start up:

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereferences at       (null)
IP[<ffff8800ca93bfcd>] 0xffff8800ca93bfcc
PGD 0
Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
Modules linked in:
CPU 3
Pid: 1, comm:swapper/0 Not tainted 3.9.2-200.fc18.x86_64 #1 LENOVO 2191/INVALID
```

The 3.8 version of the kernel worked well for me. So my question is what can I do to start the 3.9 kernel?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a kernel bug. It would appear that it's already been filed here:

- [[abrt]: irq 17: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=895951).

Don't let the initial info in the thread fool you. The bug was identified in F17, and has been continuing into F19. Read through the comments, there are certain things such as the wireless drivers that seem to make it pop up more frequently.

Comment: This is possible i use this WLAN driver (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au) but I try to black list this module and it still crash